# How and where to change chapter decoration?

Tags: chapters, decorations

I downloaded a Latex template [here](https://de.overleaf.com/articles/war-and-peace/kdgcwgqzrrfd). On every chapter (`\chapter{}`) the following decoration is displayed:
[image]

How can I change it to an individual one?

Comment: In the file `DASTmacros.tex` comment out (place a `%` in the beginning of the line) the lines: 111-113: 
`\includegraphics[height=1cm]{tikz/63}\hfill%`
`\includegraphics[height=1cm]{tikz/87}\hfill%`
`\includegraphics[height=1cm]{tikz/64}\\ `

Comment: @koleygr is it possible to design my own decoration/ornaments and insert it into  latex?

Comment: Yes it is. take a look at `tikz` package: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf